# C++ array and window exit

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm new in C++ but I know well C#, java. But no matter. I want to create checkers game emulation. I edded new event for window - load. This is source of what I've did:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             int matr[7][7];
             int i, j;
             int prevBlack = 1;
             int prevRow = 0;
             int current = 0;

             for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
             {
                 if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
                 {
                     prevBlack = 0;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     prevBlack = 1;
                 }

                 for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                 {
                     if (prevBlack == 1)
                     {
                         current = 0;
                     }
                     else if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2)
                     {
                          current = 2;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         current = 1;
                     }

                     matr[i][j] = (int)current;

                     if (current == 1 || current == 2)
                     {
                         prevBlack = 1;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        prevBlack = 0;
                     }
                 }

                 prevRow = i;
             }
         }
```

The problem is `matr[i][j] = (int)current;` At the end of this part of code my program exits. When this part of code is commented window will be displayed.

I don't know why it is so. array is 8 x 8. I need your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare your array as `matr[7][7]`, it will have the size 7x7, and valid indices will be 0..6. But you are accessing this array with indices 0..7, which results in an error.

You should declare the array as `matr[8][8]` since you need a 8x8 array.

Comment: And just to add ... because you are writing past the end of your array, you are likely overwriting the return address on the stack, so your program goes south when the function tries to return to the caller.